# What does the second field in ls -l mean on OS X? What does "number of links" mean?

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, unix, filesystems

I'm on an OS X operating System, and I don't understand what the second field in the `ls -l` command is supposed to mean. Say I am inside an empty directory, and I create a single directory inside of it:

> `mkdir folder`

When I run `ls -l` I get:

> `$ ls -l
>   total 0
>   drwxr-xr-x  2 josh  staff  68 Nov 17 15:45 folder`

In this case the number of links to the directory is 2. I believe these links refer to the original directory name and the `.` entry inside the directory.

Now I add a *file* (not a folder) to the directory:

> `touch folder/file1`

Now the output of `ls -l` looks like this:

> `$ ls -l
>   total 0
>   drwxr-xr-x  3 josh  staff  102 Nov 17 15:47 folder`

Why is there now *three* links instead of two? For each new file I add, the number of links goes up by one. I see why this makes sense if I add a new subdirectory to the directory, as a new link (`..` in the new folder) would be created, but not a new *file*. What are these extra numbers? Where do they come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link count is basically the number of places the file or directory is used. When it goes to zero, the file or directory is removed. Every file in a directory uses that directory, and a directory cannot be removed so long as there are files in it.